# Create an image or photo that can change colour in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry, tkinter-layout

I need to display an outline of a dog in a window. I then need to be able to change the colour for different part of the dog by inputting numbers into entry boxes- for example if I put a '1' in the 'head' entry box, the head changes to a yellow colour. The dog should be white by default.

I can just create 4 images (one for the head, body, legs, and tale) to change each part of the bod. I've thought about changing the rgb values of each image to change the colour, but this would also change the colour for the outline (meant to stay black). The only other thing I could think of was making a red, blue, green, yellow, blue, etc. version of each image (head, body, legs, tail), and then just displaying the red version of the image when I need to (and the same for other colours).

I need to know if there is any other way to do this (perhaps with the canvas widget?) before I code it because It will take a long time to change the colour of each image. I just have no idea where to start.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: start with following your idea of creating 4 images, one for each part of the body...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make different widgets for each part of the dog(e.g: Head, Abdomen etc.) and you will need different images for the dogs part and color, after that you can implement a button that changes the color with the 'if' function.